# How to resolve Php Error occur after update wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I update the wordpress. After that some issue were seen.

> Warning: include(images/LayerSlider_v5.3.2.png): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in
> /home/cloudbed/public_html/druits.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php
> on line 202
>
> Warning: include(images/LayerSlider_v5.3.2.png): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/cloudbed/public_html/druits.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php
> on line 202
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'images/LayerSlider_v5.3.2.png'
> for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /home/cloudbed/public_html/druits.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php
> on line 202
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/cloudbed/public_html/druits.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php:202)
> in /home/cloudbed/public_html/druits.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on
> line 1174

Comment: It's missing the LayerSlider image file. Try re-installing your LayerSlider plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable LayerSlider plugin and your site should go online without errors.
Then delete the plugin via FTP and try to install it again. 
Something has gone wrong during the update.

Comment: Thanks Daniele, i rename LayerSlider plugin, issue resoved.